# Matlab Load from relative path

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
function []= read_c3d_feat(output_list_relative)
dir_list = importdata(output_list_relative);
dim_feat = 512;
for i = 1 : size(dir_list, 1)
        dir_str = char(dir_list(i));
        feat_files = dir([dir_str, '/*.res5b']);
        num_feat = length(feat_files);
        feat = zeros(num_feat, dim_feat);
        for j = 1 : num_feat
        feat_path = strcat(dir_str, '/', feat_files(j).name);
        ...............
....................so on
```

Give me error like

Error using dir
Invalid path. The path must not contain a null character.

Error in read_c3d_feat (line 12)

```
    feat_files = dir([dir_str, '/*.res5b']);
```

Comment: what is `dir_str`?

Comment: @user2999345 *dir_str* are extracted image feature which i have extracted using Convolutional Neural Network model.

Comment: it's not a string specifying a folder on your computer? can you show an example for typical `dir_str` value?

Comment: @user2999345 file contains some random strings and symbols such as '>$ãž>(Ãk>   €   €âhx=Z<?K‹?ñI€?¿å?òÛA>   €   €   €À8@   €   €   €   €   €   €   €   €   €   €   €   €   €   €€Á=P—c<   €   €Ò(?·Ø©>   €   €   €>íb=   €ù'

Comment: So how do you expect that to be an existing directory on your machine?

Comment: @Wolfie, can you elaborate a bit more about your solution. Thanks

Comment: It isn't a solution. If you're saying you have `dir_str = '>$ãž>(Ãk> € €âhx=Z<?'`, then you're using `dir` to search through that directory, I'm not surprised you are getting errors about having null characters in your directory path

Comment: @Wolfie I have checked in directory path there is no null characters. As you can see, i am passing "output_list_relative" path like:    read_c3d_feat('C:/Users/abc/Documents/MATLAB/features') and the files are 21.res5b, 45.res5b, 18.res5b   and so on in the the features folder.

Comment: Debug your code and look at what `dir_str` is when the error is caused. The error message you have is very clear, the string (`dir_str`) which you are passing to `dir` in the line `feat_files = dir([dir_str, '/*.res5b']);` contains null characters. That means you need to look at what that string is!

Comment: @Wolfie if i am not wrong in the directory and image names does not contain any null characters.

Comment: Just show examples...

Comment: @Wolfie do you mean files  21.res5b, 45.res5b, 18.res5b???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dir_list` variable must have strings which contain null characters, as the error tells you. If you try using hard-coded strings you will see it works:

```
function read_c3d_feat(output_list_relative)
    dir_list = {'21';'45';'18'};
    for i = 1:size(dir_list, 1)
        dir_str = dir_list{i}; % Loops through '21','45','18'
        % The dir function now works because we know dir_str is a valid string
        feat_files = dir([dir_str, '/*.res5b']); 
    end
end
```

This means you need to debug your code and find out what this line is actually assigning to `dir_list`:

```
dir_list = importdata(output_list_relative);
```

Note that if `dir_list` is a cell of text entries, you should be indexing it with curly braces as above. If instead it is a matrix (because all of the entries seem to be numerical anyway) then you should be using `num2str` when passing to `dir`:

```
function read_c3d_feat(output_list_relative)
    dir_list = importdata(output_list_relative);
    dim_feat = 512;
    for i = 1:size(dir_list, 1)
        feat_files = dir([num2str(dir_list(i)), '/*.res5b']);
        % ...
```